How can I troubleshoot backup errors for SQL Server Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) certificates?
I am in the process of setting up Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) on my SQL Server database. I've successfully created a master key and a certificate for encryption. However, I am encountering an error when attempting to back up the encryption certificate. The error message suggests that there might be an issue with file permissions or the file path.
I've verified that the directory exists, I have the necessary write permissions, and the file does not already exist in the directory. Despite these checks, the backup operation fails.
What steps can I take to troubleshoot and resolve this issue? Are there any common pitfalls or additional permissions that I might be overlooking? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
